# Can Fragments use XML to define their layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Looking at the Android tutorial on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

... it seems fragments have their layouts defined programmatically. Is there a way to use the usual XML files instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed it, this is the first code snippet in the fragment documentation:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

It uses a *(supplied)* [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate a layout, in this case named `example_fragment.xml` *(inflate means parse XML and generate a layout structure out of it)*. So yes, certainly possible.

Basically all you have to do is return your fragment layout from `onCreateView()`. How you generate it inside is up to you, and since you get an inflater supplied, it's intended to use XML too.